# Can't get Emacs24 to load themes

Tags: emacs, configuration, themes, elisp

To start off, my Emacs version is `GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.12.2) of 2014-06-06 on barber, modified by Debian`, and I am running Debian Jessie as the sole OS on a 2009 Macbook Pro.

So I've downloaded lots of themes off the net that I think would make working in Emacs much more soothing, and placed them in my `~/.emacs.d/themes/` folder. I've downloaded the `emacs-goodies-el` packages. I've set the custom load path for these themes to be in that specific folder. When I start, I either get one of two things depending on if I actually try to load the themes with `(load-theme tron t)`, or not. Both errors are of the type `Symbol's value as variable is void: <!DOCTYPE`.

When I run Emacs in `--debut-init`, this is what I get:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable <!DOCTYPE)
eval-buffer()  ; Reading at buffer position 14
load-theme(jazz t)
eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/finnds/.emacs" nil t)  ; 
Reading at buffer      position 1203
load-with-code-conversion("/home/finnds/.emacs" "/home/finnds/.emacs" t t)
load("~/.emacs" t t)
#[0 "\205\262
```

When I try to load themes through `M-x customize-themes`, I get the error: `load-theme: Symbol's value as variable is void: <!DOCTYPE`, and all the colors go back to being white/light/default.

And here is my `.emacs` file, after the `custom-set-variables` and `custom-set-faces` (meaning this is put all the way at the bottom of the file):

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/")
(load-theme 'jazz t)
(require 'color-theme)
(eval-after-load "color-theme"
  '(progn
     (color-theme-initialize)))
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")))
```

I've tried doing exactly what the wiki tells me to do, and several other themesites, but I still keep getting this message. I tried searching for an answer, but there wasn't a particular one like my exact case, I found. Can anyone help me out here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are trying to load an HTML file, not an Emacs-Lisp file. It sounds like you saved the file wrong. `<!DOCTYPE` is what tells you this.
2. The [article](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/08/21/color-themes-redux/) written by Bozhidar B. and cited by him is misleading. I recommend the [EmacsWiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/ColorTheme) about this instead. It fairly compares and contrasts **color themes**, which are provided by library [**`color-theme.el`**](http://www.nongnu.org/color-theme/), and **custom themes**, which were added to vanilla Emacs 24.
3. These two kinds of theme are not the same thing, and *neither replaces the other*, in spite of what you might hear. Each has its advantages (and disadvantages) and use cases.

   And yes, you can use both -- it is not true that "*you shouldn't be doing*" this. Read the wiki page, get to know both of them, and then make up your own mind about what works for you.

   I say this with no horse in the race.  My code ([**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles) and [**Do Re Mi**](http://www.emacswiki.org/DoReMi)) that lets you cycle themes etc. supports *both* kinds of themes equally: color themes and custom themes.

Comment: This was the answer to my problem. I was putting everything correctly into the `.emacs` file, but as both you and Bozhidar has told me, the `.el` files somehow got saved as HTML files. I did not download the raw files off Github, which was why everything was all messed up.

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing the old color theme handling (based on the `color-theme` package) and the Emacs 24.x built-in support for themes, which you shouldn't be doing. I'd suggest having a look at [this article](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/08/21/color-themes-redux/) to learn more about color themes in Emacs. Here's a minimal setup example (using the zenburn theme):

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
(package-initialize)

(unless (package-installed-p 'zenburn-theme) (package-install 'zenburn-theme))

(load-theme 'zenburn t)
```

To load a theme that's locally available:

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes")
(load-theme 'theme-name t)
```

This assumes that you've placed an Emacs 24 compatible theme named `theme-name` in your `~/.emacs.d/themes` folder.

Comment: Here you are loading it from a package, yeah? How would it work when I just put them in my .emacs.d/themes/ folder? I think I already tried the methods on that site, but I will read it again.

Comment: That's mentioned in the linked article, but I've updated my article anyways.

Comment: I removed the (require 'color-theme) block down to (color-theme-initialize), and then did exactly as you wrote. Emacs now tells me the same error that I started with, `An error occured while loading 'home/finn/.emacs/ - Symbol's value as variable is void: <!DOCTYPE` Unsure what to do here, as I feel that I am doing everything correctly according to the article you just posted.

Comment: Have a look at the file you're trying to load. It might have some incorrect data in it.